# Como alterar valor da ComboBox de acordo com o caso

Tags: c#

O `combobox` tem duas opções a Opção Letra e opção números.

Ao setar um deles, preciso que apareça em outro `comboBox` somente as informações correspondentes a opção selecionada.

O `comboBox` não e ligado a um `db`, e sim tem conteúdo na propriedade itens do componente.

Selecionando `Letras` aparecer só Letras,

Selecionando `Números` aparecer só os números.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer de várias formas, mas sugiro que como você está começando, tente fazer da seguinte forma para exercitar a lógica.

1. Crie um combobox com o nome **cmbTipo** e adicione os itens "Letras"
   e "Números".
2. Crie um combobox com o nome **cmbOpcoes**.
3. Adicione um
   manipulador de eventos *SelectIndexChanged* ao cmbTipo clicando duas
   vezes sobre ele ou na aba Eventos da janela de propriedades.
4. Altere
   o código conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```cs
private void cmbTipo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbTipo.Text.Equals("Letras"))
    {
        cmbOpcoes.DataSource = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    }
    else
    {
        cmbOpcoes.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}
```